# What could I do to further reduce my finetuning time of 67 hours with the following configuration?

Tags: llama-2, fine-tuning

I am taking a large text dataset and fitting them into 19k rows. Each row is exactly 4096 tokens (not characters), which is the maximum context length of llama 2 7B.

```
GPU: 80GB
My other configurations are 
Batch size: 4
Peft method: Qlora
Quantization: 4 but
Epochs: 1
Rank: 1
Grad accum steps: 4
Learning rate: 0.0001
Optimiser: adamw_apex_fused
```

Resultant total steps: 19196
Estimated time: 57 hours

p.s: Increasing the batchsize even by 1 is giving CUDA OOM

Comment: I only read about this a bit. Have you checked running this with the Huggingface Transformers Trainer class instead? See [Train with PyTorch Trainer](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/training#train-with-pytorch-trainer) which allows you to tweak the hyperparameters in the TrainingArguments class, I do not know how it optimizes by itself. Mind: "Trainer does not automatically evaluate model performance during training. You’ll need to pass Trainer a function to compute and report metrics. The  Evaluate library provides a simple accuracy function you can load with the evaluate.load".

Comment: There is also the fine-tuning with AutoTrain, see [LLM Finetuning](https://huggingface.co/docs/autotrain/llm_finetuning). Perhaps, that takes care of speeding up things?

Comment: I am doing this fine tuning through Hugging face Autotrain. I am wondering if this is the maximum optimisation I could do.